# Call object per their ids and append the result to a big final object

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

As per title I have this array of objects:

```
myArr=[ {
"id": "25a91eccf70ae3eb",
"name": "ParentID",

},
{
"id": "25a91eccf70ae3eb",
"name": "Child1",


},
{
"key": "25a91eccf70ae3eb",
"name": "Child2",


}]
```

And would like to have each object named with is own id and append them to a big object in the following format

```
myBigObject={
 ParentID:{
id: "ParentID", 
name: "Parent",

 },
child1_ID:{
id: "child1_ID",
name: "Child1",

 },
child2_ID:{
id: "child2_ID",
name: "Child2",

}
```

How can I achieve that?
Thanks

Comment: The formatting of this question is pretty confusing, and you are giving the steps you require, but not really defining exactly where you are stuck or what the problem is.

Comment: Updated->I would like to  achieve point 2 3 and 4 together with point 1

Comment: I'd like someone to write my app for me, but I don't ask on Stack Overflow. There are questions answered for each of the steps here. Please break your questions down, do some research on each part, and if you're stuck on one, ask just the one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes I thought it can be made in one go but you re right is better to split it up.

Comment: Look at `Array.prototype.reduce`. If going from an array to a single value, that tends to be a good fit. You can supply an initial value to it, I'd do an empty object literal `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple readable solution:

```js
var myArr = [{
        "key": "25a91eccf71ae3eb",
        "name": "ParentID",

    },
    {
        "key": "25a91eccf72ae3eb",
        "name": "Child1",


    },
    {
        "key": "25a91eccf73ae3eb",
        "name": "Child2",


    }
]


let finalObj = {}
const first_node = myArr[0];
for (let item of myArr) {
    finalObj[item.key] = { 'id': item.key, "name": item.name };
    if (item.key == first_node.key) {
        finalObj[item.key].ChildrenID = [];
        continue;
    }
    finalObj[first_node.key].ChildrenID.push(item.key);
}

console.log(finalObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use `Object.assign()` and `map()` to accomplish this.

```js
const myArr = [
    {
        "id": "25a91eccf70ae3eb",
        "name": "ParentID",
    },
    {
        "id": "25a91eccf70ae3eb",
        "name": "Child1",
    },
    {
        "id": "25a91eccf70ae3eb",
        "name": "Child2",
    }
];

const arrMap = myArr.map(({ id, name }, i) => {
    return i === 0 ? // if loop is at first element
        { parent_ID: { id, name } } : // return parent 
        { [`child${i}_ID`]: { id, name } }; // otherwise corresponding child
});

const result = Object.assign({}, ...arrMap); // assign to object
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question, the sample object has the values for every 'key' property as same. I have changed that assuming all the keys would be different. Please check the solution below -

```js
const myArr=[
{
"key": "123",
"name": "ParentID",
},
{
"key": "456",
"name": "Child1",
},
{
"key": "789",
"name": "Child2",
}];

function modifyArray(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((resultObj, currObj, index) => {
    resultObj = {
      ...resultObj,
      [currObj.key]: {
        id: currObj.key,
        name: currObj.name
      }
    }
    return resultObj;
  }, {});
}

const arr1 = modifyArray(myArr);

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like most of what you're after can be accomplished using [the .forEach() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to run a specific function over every element of the array (this will be where you change the contents) and then adding the resulting object into your big output object.